# Compiler error 1: constructor contains more than 0 args

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, xna-4.0

I am a beginner with C, C#, XNA, and I am trying to follow some tutorials online, but when I try to make a paddle object from a different class, I get the error that the constructor does not contain 0 arguments. I dont know if the error is in my game class or my paddle class.

important code in my game class:

```
Paddle paddle; // creates a paddle
...
public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    screenRectangle = new Rectangle(
        0,
        0,
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth,
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);
}
...
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    Texture2D tempTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("paddle");
    paddle = new Paddle(tempTexture, screenRectangle);
}
```

and this is the beginning of my paddle class

```
public class Paddle : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent
{
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 motion;
    float paddleSpeed = 8f;

    KeyboardState keyboardState;
    GamePadState gamePadState;

    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle screenBounds;

    public Paddle(Texture2D texture, Rectangle screenBounds)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.screenBounds = screenBounds;
        SetInStartPosition();
    }
```

I was following the tutorial at http://xnagpa.net/xna4/beginnertuts/BreakingOut1.pdf

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: Just a comment. `Paddle paddle` does not 'create the paddle.' It *declares* the paddle. `paddle = ...` creates the paddle.

Comment: The compiler error should say which line of which file the error is located in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somewhere you are saying `paddle = new Paddle();`

Comment: WOW! I accidentally had old code mixed in with the new stuff that was creating the error. as soon as I removed this 1 line, 50 more showed up. thanks!